# Set winner after turn based game Google API Android

Tags: android, google-api, multiplayer

I'm creating a turn based game on the Android platform using the API provided by Google.
At the end of the latest turn (in my case the third one), I'd like to set the winner but I have not found any API that permits this. Naturally I have all the data at the end of the game to set it.

I've not read something in the documentation - does this feature exist or should I handle it myself?

Comment: Can we see some code, your question is a bit confusing. Also, I think you might be confusing the meaning of `API`.

Comment: In previous API that I have used, ScoreLoop, I was able at the end of the turn base game to set the winner. So I'd like to know if there's something similar into Google API

Comment: None of you know something about it?

Comment: I just think no one really understand what you are asking. If ScoreLoop worked why not use it again? Turn based games aren't that difficult to program but without seeing code we would literally be creating a major portion of the functionality of the game for you.

Comment: Please check the example: 

1) player A invite player B to play. 
2) A play the first turn and his score is 50, B play and his score is 60.
3) now the game is finished and player B is the winner because his score is 60.How can I set that the user B is the winner of the turn based game.

Answer (score 0):

```
String playerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient());
String myOponentId = mMatch.getParticipantId(playerId);

opponentResult = new ParticipantResult(myOponentId,
                    ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_WIN, 1);
            creatorResult = new ParticipantResult(playerId,
                    ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_LOSS, 2);

Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(getApiClient(), mMatch.getMatchId(),mMatch.getData(), creatorResult,opponentResult )
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                        processResult(result);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll check as soon as possible but from what I found it's the solution that I've requested. Thanks a lot.